# python handles long ints differently on Windows and Unix

Tags: python

The current number of milliseconds since the epoch is `1395245378429`; on unix (64 bit / Ubuntu / python 2.7), you can do:

```
>>> t = 1395245378429
>>> type(t)
<type 'int'>
>>> t = 1395245378429L
>>> type(t)
<type 'long'>
>>> int(t)
1395245378429
>>> type(int(t)
<type 'int'>
```

but on Windows (also 64 bit / python 2.7), this happens:

```
>>> t = 1395245378429
>>> type(t)
<type 'long'>
>>> int(t)
1395245378429L
>>> type(int(t))
<type 'long'>
```

so, the following weird observations:

- on Windows, `int(<long>)` returns a long
- the same number is treated as a long in Windows, but an int on unix

I can't see anything obvious in the documentation to say this is correct behaviour; is there a (correct) way to convert the long to an int (i.e. so it can be used in a method which requires an int argument)

Comment: Get around *what*, exactly?  What consequence of the int/long transition happening at a different value are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Note that even though you have 64-bit Windows you can still have a 32-bit Python installation, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: Note that `int(20000000000000000000)` will return a `long` in both python 32 and 64 bit because that number is bigger than `2**64`. The conversion from `int` to `long` is almost always performed silently since, other then performance of operation, there shouldn't be any significant change in behaviour. I don't know of a situation that raises `OverflowError` between integer types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python uses C `long` for the `int` type, and even on Windows this is limited to 32-bit. You can see your platform's current maximum native `int` size by inspecting the [`sys.maxint` value](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint):

> The largest positive integer supported by Python’s regular integer type. This is at least 2**31-1. The largest negative integer is `-maxint-1` — the asymmetry results from the use of 2’s complement binary arithmetic.

and from the [Numeric Types section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex):

> Plain integers (also just called integers) are implemented using `long` in C, which gives them at least 32 bits of precision (`sys.maxint` is always set to the maximum plain integer value for the current platform, the minimum value is `-sys.maxint - 1`).

Unless you are directly interacting with a C extension library that doesn't support the Python `long` type, there is no need to worry about when Python uses `int` and when you need to use `long`. In Python 3, the separate `long` type has been removed entirely.

Comment: Ah, ok - I was pretty sure I'd installed 64-bit python, obviously not! And this is the 1st time I'd ever come across a 32-/64-bit issue to find out...

Comment: Perhaps unfortunately (for me), I do seem to be using a C extension which doesn't accept longs, hence finding this issue

Comment: Python's internal representation of `<int>` uses a C long type. Even on 64-bit Windows, Microsoft defines a C long to be 32 bits. So it won't matter if you use a 32 or 64-bit version of Windows. Most (all?) 64-bit Unix systems define a C long to be 64 bits. Speaking from personal experience, the difference in the definition of a C long causes lots of difficulties with C extensions.

Comment: @casevh: Ah, so this is perhaps a Windows issue after all.

Comment: @ casevh : this has also caused me a lot of issues when trying to have a unified code across platforms to interface with C extensions. This may not help you if you don't want to depend on numpy but the workaround I have found is tu use the types numpy.int32 and numpy.int64 which are consistent across platforms.