# Why does int(maxint) give a long, but int(int(maxint)) give an int? Is this a NumPy bug?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, int, long-integer

Pretty self-explanatory (I'm on Windows):

```
>>> import sys, numpy
>>> a = numpy.int_(sys.maxint)
>>> int(a).__class__
<type 'long'>
>>> int(int(a)).__class__
<type 'int'>
```

Why does calling `int` once give me a `long`, whereas calling it twice gives me an `int`?

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Also gives me an int with Python 2.7.6 and numpy 1.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Python 2.7.12 numpy 1.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: The results I mentioned were on Linux. I just tested on Windows with Numpy 1.12.1 and I do reproduce your results. For 2147483646 it gives an `int`, but for 2147483647 it's a `long`.

Comment: Related: [python handles long ints differently on Windows and Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22513445/846892)

Comment: I get the same off-by-one error on Linux with `numpy.int64(9223372036854775807)`, which is converted to `long` while 1 less than that is converted to `int`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Not really related to the question; see my edit.

Comment: Explore `a.item()` and `int(sys.maxint)`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Huh, I didn't even know `item()` exists. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is specific to Numpy and Python 2. In Python 3 there are no separate `int` and `long` types.

The behaviour happens due to an off-by-one error in numpy. `int(x)` with one argument converts `x` to number by calling [`PyNumber_Int(x)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/intobject.c#L1081). `PyNumber_Int` then specifically takes the [path for `int` subclasses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/abstract.c#L1632), as `int64` returned by `numpy.int_` is a subclass of `int`:

```c
m = o->ob_type->tp_as_number;
if (m && m->nb_int) { /* This should include subclasses of int */
    /* Classic classes always take this branch. */
    PyObject *res = m->nb_int(o);
    if (res && (!PyInt_Check(res) && !PyLong_Check(res))) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "__int__ returned non-int (type %.200s)",
                     res->ob_type->tp_name);
        Py_DECREF(res);
        return NULL;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now, for this code calls `a->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_int`, which is implemented in [numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c.src](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e332ba4314bf874b1c7d17d82a2f1bf1766ece69/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c.src#L1402). This is the location for code that is parametrized for different types; this one for `<typename>_int` method that is used to fill the [`nb_int`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e332ba4314bf874b1c7d17d82a2f1bf1766ece69/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c.src#L1609) method slot. It has the following off-by one `if` there:

```
if(LONG_MIN < x && x < LONG_MAX)
    return PyInt_FromLong(x);
```

both operators should be `<=` instead. With `<` there, neither `LONG_MIN` nor `LONG_MAX` pass the condition and they're instead are converted into a `PyLong` at [line 1432](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e332ba4314bf874b1c7d17d82a2f1bf1766ece69/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c.src#L1432):

```
return @func@(x);
```

with `@func@` being replaced by `PyLong_FromLongLong` in the case of `int_`. Thus, `long(sys.maxint)` is returned.

Now, as the `sys.maxint` is still representable by `int`, `int(long(sys.maxint))` returns an `int`; likewise `int(sys.maxint + 1)` returns a `long`.

Answer (score 4):

As proposed in the (now-deleted) other answer, this does seem to be a bug due to an incorrect use of `<` instead of `<=`, but it's not coming from the code cited in the other answer. That code is part of the printing logic, which isn't involved here.

I believe the code that handles `int` calls on NumPy scalars is generated from a [template](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e332ba4314bf874b1c7d17d82a2f1bf1766ece69/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c.src#L1402) in `numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c.src`, the relevant part for signed integer dtypes being

```
    if(LONG_MIN < x && x < LONG_MAX)
        return PyInt_FromLong(x);
#endif
    return @func@(x);
```

For integers strictly between `LONG_MIN` and `LONG_MAX`, this code produces an `int`. For an integer with value `LONG_MAX`, it falls back on the `return @func@(x);` case, where `@func@` is substituted by an appropriate function from the `PyLongFrom*` family by the template engine.

Thus, calling `int` on a NumPy int with value `LONG_MAX` produces a `long`, but since the result is representable as an int, calling `int` on the result again produces an `int`.