# Incorrect value for big integers sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

So in short when inserting huge integers to sqlite3 database like example `302140846680178689` it ends up saved as `302140846680178700` and I don't know why sometimes the last 1-2 digits are incorrect.

I say sometimes because it isn't consistent. For example `197918569894379520` will  remain `197918569894379520`.

Python code to recreate (I'm using 3.7.6 64bit):

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("example.db")

some_id = 302140846680178689
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE example(one TEXT, two INTEGER, three BIG INT)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES (?,?,?)", (some_id, some_id, some_id))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The resulting table looks like:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     one(TEXT)      |    two(INTEGER)    |   three(BIG INT)   |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 302140846680178689 | 302140846680178700 | 302140846680178700 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I expected same result for integer and big int as per point [3.1.1. of the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) it seems big int is just another name for integer and it will be integer regardless? Sqlite will internally manage the size as quote `INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.`

So the maximum size for integer seems to be 2^63-1 which is big enough to fit `302140846680178689` and it also doesn't seem to be some rounding error from the module as `print(int(float(302140846680178689)) - 302140846680178689)` gives `-1` and yet I have difference of 11.

Update: Giving more info as per questions in comments

```
print(sqlite3.version)
> 2.6.0

print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
> 3.28.0

c.execute("SELECT typeof(two) FROM example;")
print(c.fetchall())
> [('integer',)]
```

Adding this at end of script:

```
print(type(some_id))
> <class 'int'>
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the problem using SQLite 3.31.1 python 3.7 on Windows 10. Could it be an issue with SQLite 3.1.1?

Comment: Also can't reproduce with python 3.5.2 and sqlite 3.30.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. What does `print(type(some_id))` added to the end of that script show when you run it? And `SELECT typeof(two) FROM example;` from in sqlite3?

Comment: Are you running the code on Windows or Linux ? I recently found out that even on a 64-bit Windows Python would actually treat `int` as 32-bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914865/index-number-to-large-for-python/59915161#59915161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the irony is that I myself didn't test the code I posted with manual queries.

I didn't want to manually make queries with code just to view data but instead I used sqlite viewer, more specifically https://sqliteonline.com/

Now I tested with manual query from code and it returned the correct value however opening the database in that viewer returns incorrect values for some reason (it really didn't occur to me that the viewer was at fault since it's literally just querying`SELECT * FROM example`, now I even tried different versions of it and still the same incorrect result).

Edit reply from dev: The viewer works on the library "SQLite.js" and the maximum number in JavaScript is 9007199254740991 so any number more will be rounded.